# Этимология слов "Господь" / "Господи" и в чём разница между ними?

Tags: этимология, окончания, суффиксы

В русском языке для упоминания бога чаще всего используются две формы обращения — `Господь` и `Господи`. Интересует происхождение этих двух форм, а также различия между ними, а именно: как слово `Господь` преобразовалось в `Господи`? Есть ли у суффикса/окончания `-и` какая-то смысловая нагрузка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В древнерусском (и старославянском) языке слово *господь* относилось к *ĭ-склонению (с некоторыми отклонениями). В отличие от современного русского литературного языка, в тех языках также имелся особый падеж — звательный (использовавшийся, в общем, при обращениях). Окончание -и в *господи* — это именно окончание звательного падежа единственного числа (ср. *господь* в именительном падеже ед. ч.).

Итак, -и — окончание звательного падежа единственного числа, а *господи* — соответствующая форма слова *господь*.

О происхождении основы: оно до конца не ясно. Вероятно, в *господь* содержится (этимологически) тот же корень, что и в слове *гость* (ср. лат. *hospes, hospitis*), а также еще один корень со значением «тождественности лица» (ср. лтш. *pats* ‘сам, самый’, ‘сам (хозяин)’, лат. *potis* ‘могущественный’). (По РЭС А. Е. Аникина.)